# cash-dom check if option selected

Tags: javascript, cash-dom

When I'm trying to check an options is selected using by [cash-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cash-dom), it throws an error like following:

> Uncaught DOMException: Element.mozMatchesSelector: ':selected' is not a valid selector

This is my code:

```js
const options = cash('option');
options.map(i=>{
  console.log(i,options.eq(i));
  console.info(options.eq(i).is(':selected'))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, just change

```js
console.info(options.eq(i).is(':selected'))
```

with:

```js
console.info(options.eq(i).is('[selected]'))
```